# Problem when installing a plugin manually on Jenkins

Tags: java, android, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am facing a couple of problems when I try to deploy a plugin to Jenkins, ([android-signing](https://plugins.jenkins.io/android-signing/)), the plugin is old, but it was used back then for the project I am working on to sign android APKs, the keystore password is nowhere to be found.

The keystore certificate is saved in the credentials plugin on Jenkins, and I was able to retrieve the password on the server through the plugin's "credentials.xml" but it is decrypted, I don't know how to decrypt it, even though, I prefer to retrieve to keystore password instead of using the plugin because it is not being maintained anymore and has [security vulnerabilities](https://www.jenkins.io/security/advisory/2022-07-27/#SECURITY-2404). I didn't want to enable the plugin because of this, but when I went to their [GitHub page](https://github.com/jenkinsci/android-signing-plugin) I saw that the owner of plugin decided not to devote any more time to work on it but if there are issues, people should create PRs, and he will check them, approve, and merge the code.

anyway, someone created a [pull request](https://github.com/jenkinsci/android-signing-plugin/pull/3) that supposedly is going to fix this vulnerability, the owner approved, but didn't create a release, so I think at this point I am supposed to clone the project, build the project, and then deploy it manually on Jenkins, since there was no provided `.jar` or `.hpi` file for the latest update on the plugin.

When running `mvn clean install` or `mvn package` in console, the installing works fine, but when it comes to the `Tests` part, I always get the same error even after trying to fix it, which has to do back-slashes/forward-slashes, and different file locations like this

`unexpected char: '\' @ line 6, column 23. androidHome: 'C:\Development\android-signing-plugin\target\test-classes\win-android'`

and this

`Expected: a string starting with "C:/Development/android-signing-plugin/target/test-classes/android" but: was "C:\Development\android-signing-plugin\target\test-classes\android\build-tools\1.0\zipalign"`

If someone could try running `mvn clean install` and come up with a solution to this problem, that would be great.
But anyway, I decided to skip the testing part using this command `mvn clean install -DskipTests` then it was built successfully, afterwards, I went to `Manage Jenkins > Manage Plugins > Advanced settings`, I chose the `.hpi` file that was generated by the build and deployed it. It worked fine, because when I checked the version installed it was the newer one which is the 2.2.6, however, the security vulnerability still showed on Jenkins I'm not sure why, but I think it is due to the fact that on [Jenkins update center](https://updates.jenkins.io/current/update-center.json) (search for android-signing) the last updated version of the plugin was 2.2.5 and the new 2.2.6 is still not hosted by Jenkins update center, so it still shows the security issue, please correct me if I'm wrong here.

Now to my actual main concerns that made me write this post, in my case, what is the best way to keep signing the release APK? is there a way to decrypt the encrypted keystore password?
if not, is it safe to enable the plugin on Jenkins (after the update) even if it still shows the security issue?
If i want to revert back to 2.2.5, (knowing that I backed up the server, and copied the plugin folder from the Jenkins server, before deploying the plugin), would I lose any configurations? or since it depends on Credentials plugin, it would be fine?
Also, regarding the security issue that still shows after updating, is it because of what is specified in the Jenkins update center?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Looks like the tests simply don't support Windows paths. Try building on a Linux machine, or if you don't have one available in WSL2.

Comment: Regarding the signing, you can use credentials from Jenkins by simply using a `withCredentials` block. Inside the block you can make the credentials available as environment variables. Just make sure to not use these credentials outside the `withCredentials` block, because Jenkins will only obfuscate credentials inside the block, not outside it.

Comment: @RobSpoor I don't have a Linux machine, I will try it on WSL or on a MacBook, but anyway, the Jenkins server is hosted on a windows machine, would that cause the same paths problem?


Will I be able to sign the android app using the `withCredentials` block? if yea then this way I can actually get rid of the plugin, right?

Comment: At work we use `withCredentials` with a file credential (the GPG private key) and a secret text (the GPG passphrase). The GPG private key is imported into a new GPG store (using `--homedir`), then the necessary settings (key id, key ring file, passphrase) are passed to Gradle for the actual build, where the signing plugin uses these. See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/signing_plugin.html